# Why is there a drop in the numbers in the risk set in left truncation survival analysis

Tags: r, survival-analysis

Can someone please provide a straightforward explanation as to why I'm seeing this behavior when I estimate the KM curves accounting for left truncation:
[image]

More specifically, at the beginning of the study, there should be a total of 462 patients, not (12 + 21) 33 patients only.

**Code to reproduce**

```
library(survival)
library(KMsurv) #for survival dataset
library(survminer) #for plot

data(channing)

adj_fit <- survfit(Surv(ageentry, age, death) ~ gender, data = channing)
survminer::ggsurvplot(adj_fit, data = channing, risk.table = T)
```

You should receive the warning message that comes from `Surv` since there are 4 left-truncated patients; however, it doesn't seem to explain the graph's behavior:

```
Warning message:
In Surv(ageentry, age, death) : Stop time must be > start time, NA created
```

**EDIT**

Upon closer inspection, I can compute the numbers `12` and `21`.

```
#for males
channing %>% 
  filter(gender == 1,
         ageentry <= 842,
         age >= 842) %>%
  nrow()

#for females
channing %>%
  filter(gender == 2,
         ageentry <= 802,
         age >= 802) %>%
  nrow()
```

The cutoffs 842 and 802 were rounded down to 800, since the risk table displays the counts at time intervals of 100 months.

The question still remains as to why accounting for left truncation would cause the Kaplan-Meier estimate for males to drop down to 0 at around time point 800 -- that would imply that everyone died, which is clearly not the case...

Comment: It would seem that NA's being created should reduce the number at risk but agree that those numbers look wrong. What about the other warning: `Warning message:
Vectorized input to element_text() is not officially supported.
Results may be unexpected or may change in future versions of ggplot2.`?

Comment: `channing` dataset is not an interval censored data but a right censored data. You should run `survfit(Surv(time=time, event=death) ~ gender, data = channing)` instead.

Comment: `channing` is also left truncated so how do I deal with that? I know that you can do `Surv(time, time2, event)` in a `coxph` for left truncated data (See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/106271/survival-analysis-in-r-with-left-truncated-data)

Comment: @latlio You first need to distinguish between *truncation* and *censoring*. Left-truncated data will not appear in the dataset (that's why it is *truncated*) and what we can deal with `Surv(time, time2, event)` is *censored* data. Actually, `channing` dataset is not left-censored, because the start time is defined by `ageentry`, which is not ambiguous.

Comment: You also need to specify the definition of survival rate. What you are doing is to estimate the survival rate starting from their date of birth.

Comment: Channing is meant to be an example of left-truncated, right-censored data (Klein 2003) (see Survival Analysis Techniques for Censored and Truncated data)

Comment: Yes I agree with definition of survival rate, I cross-posted on cross-validated, and I got a sufficient answer (see here to get on the same page: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/506273/when-is-the-unconditional-kaplan-meier-estimate-meaningful-in-left-truncated-rig/506354?noredirect=1#comment935398_506354)

Comment: @latlio I'm sorry for my late reply and also very sorry for my lack of knowledge. I took a look at the reference book and cross-validated. The meaningless result obtained without `type="counting"` is exactly what is mentioned in pp.124-125, and the one obtained with `type="counting"` seems to be what is referred to as *the conditional probability of surviving beyond age t, given survival to age 68* (pp.125). Thank you for providing me with this chance to learn about this topic.